# Python: how to get number of days from fixed past date to now

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Python to get the number of days from an arbitrary fixed past date (e.g., 2016/03/15) to now. I see that I can use `datetime` to specify now and the past date, and get a timedelta containing the number of days between:

```
>>> noo = datetime.now()
>>> then = noo.replace(month=3, day=15, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
>>> diffy = noo - then
>>> diffy
datetime.timedelta(43, 65233, 748370)
```

But, being still pretty new to Python, I don't know how to extract the number of days (43) from the timedelta. Can somebody help me out with this?

Comment: According to the [`timedelta` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) `days` is an attribute that you can access directly.

Comment: `help(datetime)` and `help(datetime.timedelta)` are what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look at the `.days` property:

```
diffy.days
```

e.g.:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> noo = datetime.now()
>>> then = noo.replace(month=3, day=15, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
>>> diffy = noo - then
>>> diffy
datetime.timedelta(43, 55471, 209431)
>>> diffy.days
43
```

One thing to watch out for is the normalization of negative timedeltas... The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) even says that these can be surprising...

Comment: I thought it would probably be something that simple. Thanks--I'll accept your answer as soon as the site will let me!